# Numpy / C++ integers not promoted to python integers?

Tags: python, numpy, printing

The following Python 3.6 code running on Windows:

```
print (111111, row [maxMins [deflectionIndex]])
print (222222, row [maxMins [deflectionIndex + 1]])
print (333333, row [maxMins [deflectionIndex]] - row [maxMins [deflectionIndex + 1]])
print (444444, 29697 - -23272)
print (555555, origRow.dtype)
print (666666, type (row [maxMins [deflectionIndex]])
a = row [maxMins [deflectionIndex]]
print  (777777, type (a))
```

in which `row` is obtained from numpy array `origRow` as follows:

```
    row = [origRow [0]]
    for sample in origRow [1:]:
        while sample == row [-1]:   # Avoid completely flat curve segments, since the max-min algorithm can't deal them
            sample += 0.000001 * (ev.random () - 0.5)
        row.append (sample)
```

prints:

```
111111 29697
222222 -23272
333333 -12567
444444 52969
555555 int16
666666 <class 'numpy.int16'> <class 'numpy.int16'>
777777 <class 'numpy.int16'>
```

I would expect the lines tagged with 333333 and 444444 to show identical computation results.

Are numpy integers treated differently from Python integers?
This means that the semantics change if I first assign a numpy array element to a Python variable, because it will be transformed into a Python unlimited length integer? [EDIT: No!]

It's clear that they are stored as C++ fixed length integers, hence can wrap around.
But why aren't they promoted to Python integers if the numerical range of a C++ integer is too small?

Comment: `29697 - -23272` what does this do? can we replace it with `+`

Comment: It subtracts -23272 from 29697,  just  as the line above, only with a completely different result!

Comment: okay got it. thanks.

Comment: What's the numpy dtype of the row array?

Comment: They are not treated differently, they are different types. Assignment in python does not trigger any transformations or promotions, it just binds names to objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overflowing/wrapping, because your array is of 16-bit values.

For signed 16-bit variables, the value 52969 "wraps" around to -12567.  When you do the computation using numpy values (e.g. your line 33333), you'll get the wrapped result.

When you do the computation using Python types (e.g. your line 44444), you'll get full precision integer results without overflowing or wrapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Even if I assign it to a Python scalar variable it keeps type numpy.int16. And if I multiply it by 1, it becomes numpy.int32. Good to know! So indeed the whole numpy typesystem coexists with the native Python typesystem, which for me had some unexpected results...

Comment: @Jacques, you can't assign something to a `Python scalar variable`.  `x = 111111` followed by `x = data[0]` does not change the original scalar.  It changes what `x` references.  Variables don't have a type; `type(x)` gives the type of the object that `x` references.

Comment: @hpaulj Right! Sometimes I forget how logical and regular Python is... Still I would expect that in <aNumPyArray> [<anIndex>] the indexing operation somehow converts the value. But of course that couldn't be since it would render simple assignment of array elements in NumPy utterly slow. It's all very logical if you think carefully about it. But still it took me quite some hours to find the cause of the problem in my application.